Help identifying 4 pin component
Need help identifying this board component, top middle. I believe it is 1R2 017e. Its a 1 or an I. The dimensions are: 3.16mm x 2.67mm. Contains 4 pins.


Add the part number into your question title to help attract someone who recognises the part. Welcome to EE.SE.

It's a Panasonic AQY221R2M PhotoMOS relay.


(Source: aliexpress.ru)

I appreciate you!
